# Postgresql: Loop through each table and check for column?

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin

I am trying to write a simple `SQL` query in `pgAdmin` to LOOP through each table in a database and change a specified column name IF it exists. I have never coded in `SQL` but after searching through many forums have managed to come up with:

```
DO
BEGIN
FOR i IN SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
LOOP
   IF SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'i.table_name'
 THEN
   ALTER TABLE i.table_name RENAME COLUMN old_column_name TO new_column_name
END IF;
END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can skip `information_schema.tables` entirely. Just:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
    rec record;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN 
        SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name
        FROM information_schema.columns 
        WHERE column_name = 'x'
    LOOP
        EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %I.%I RENAME COLUMN %I TO newname;',
            rec.table_schema, rec.table_name, rec.column_name);
    END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

with appropriate substitutions for `'x'` and `newname`. Or make it into a function that takes them as parameters, whatever.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's a lot clearer now. This saved me loads of manual work. :)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like you need to query `tables`, just query `columns` for the old column name, and get the table it's in.

You will need to use [Dynamic SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ecpg-dynamic.html) to do the renames.

See [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html) on how to loop through query results. This of course needs to be done in a PL/pgSQL function.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer for your question was posted above.  Alternately if you are trying to simply drop a column from all your tables as I was trying to do, then you can do it this way

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
  rec record;
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN
  SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name
  FROM information_schema.columns
  WHERE column_name = 'my_column_name_to_drop'
  LOOP
    EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %I.%I DROP %I;',
                   rec.table_schema, rec.table_name, rec.column_name);
  END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Where `my_column_name_to_drop` is the actual column you are searching for.